# Can't get Jetpack infinite-scroll to work in custom theme

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I've created a custom Wordpress theme for a client and am trying to utilize Jetpack's infinite-scroll feature but cannot get it to work. I'm relatively new to Wordpress, but have spent hours trying to resolve this.

Here is a link to the site as is:

http://wpportmanteau.cityonfilm.com/

I've added theme support for infinite scroll in my functions.php file

```
<?php 

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
'type'           => 'scroll',
'footer_widgets' => false,
'container'      => 'content',
'wrapper'        => true,
'render'         => false,
'posts_per_page' => false,
) );

?>
```

I'm using the get_template_part function as per this article:

http://ottopress.com/2012/jetpack-and-the-infinite-scroll/

The content.php file generating the posts is as follow:

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
```

```
    <div class="window preview">
            <div class="poster preview" style="background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>); background-size:cover;">
                <h2><?php the_time('m/d'); ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="info preview">
                <div class="postInfo">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                    <p> <?php the_tags('',' / ',''); ?> </p>
                    <?php echo sharing_display(); ?>
                </div>
                    <div class="toolbar">
                        <a target="_blank" class="large button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Download', true); ?>" title="Download"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/dl.png"></a><a class="large button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Stream', true); ?>" title="Stream"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/stream.png"></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I know that the structure of my posts is a little strange but I'm not having any trouble generating them.

Thanks in advance for any advice/support. Let me know if I can provide any more information to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You need to most likely need to define the render parameter. So would define the get_template_part. Jetpack uses `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );`by default but if your theme uses a different file names or template part location then you will need to define it.

```
function theme_slug_infinite_scroll_render() {
    get_template_part( 'content-post', 'standard' );
}
```

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-infinite-scroll/

http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/